# How come one integral produces two different functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

How come one integral produces two different functions?

$$\underbrace{\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx}=\underbrace{-\frac{1}{x+1}+C}$$

$\hspace{150pt}same \hspace{45pt}different$

$$\overbrace{\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx}=\overbrace{\frac{x}{x+1}+C}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If two (nice enough) functions have the same derivative, the only explanation is that the two functions only differ by a constant.

---

So, whenever you get a result where one integral equals two very different functions $f$ and $g$, there are two options:

1. You made a mistake in the calculation.
2. The two functions actually differ by only a constant.

---

It's easy to check the two options by calculating the derivative, in your case:

1. $\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)' = \frac{1\cdot(x+1)-1\cdot x}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$
2. $\left(-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)' = -\frac{0\cdot(x+1) - 1\cdot 1}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

So, it appears the two functions really **do** have the same derivative, so they **must** differ by only a constant.

You can see this by writing $$\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{x + 1 - 1}{x + 1} = \frac{x+1}{x+1} + \frac{-1}{x+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{x+1},$$

or, if you want a more general method to calculate what the difference between the functions is, you can always just calculate $f-g$ which in your case is

$$\frac{x}{x+1} - \left(-\frac{1}{x+1}\right) = \frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{x + 1}{x+1} = 1.$$

From the equation $\frac{x}{x+1} - \left(-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)=1$, you can clearly see that $$\frac{x}{x+1}=-\frac{1}{x+1}+1$$

Answer (score 6):

As always with this type of problem, it comes down to the constant. $$\frac{x}{x+1}=-\frac{1}{x+1}+1$$